# Why won't this Ruby script in a Rake task pick up the Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have written a Ruby script, that I'd like to run as a Rake task. The following is my `data.rake` file:

```
namespace :data do
  namespace :fixtures do
    desc "Save fixtures to JSON file"
    task :file do
      bundle exec ruby "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/get_fixtures.rb"
    end

    desc "Save fixtures to DB"
    task db: :environment do
      # puts League.all.inspect
      bundle exec ruby "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/save_fixtures_to_db.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

On the `data:fixutres:db` task, the commented line works fine and shows the League data as an ActiveRecord query, whereas the Ruby script throws the following error when using `League.new` inside of it:

```
`save_to_db': uninitialized constant League (NameError)
    from /home/fred/workspace/plprediction/lib/tasks/save_fixtures_to_db.rb:134:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby...]
/home/fred/workspace/plprediction/lib/tasks/data.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@havenprediction/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@havenprediction/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => data:fixtures:db
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am lost here. I don't know why the environment is only available within the rake task, and not the Ruby script in the rake task.

Comment: if you require your app in your script via `require File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)` does it work?

Comment: Yes, Anthony, that works. However, I'd prefer not to hard-code it, when there's a way that is _supposed_ to work, but isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment is only available within the rake task, and not the Ruby script in the rake task because of the way you've structured the Rake invocation.  You are kicking off an additional process (which would need to load the environment itself to "get back" to where your Rake process already is).

Your `lib/tasks/get_fixtures.rb` tasks may work because it only uses Ruby code, not Rails.  (This is speculation, since that code isn't available.)

In this situation, I commonly put the contents of something like `save_fixtures_to_db.rb` in a Class method, and invoke that method from rake.  Here's an example:

```
class League
  def self.save_fixtures_to_db
    # Your ruby code here.
  end
end
```

The rake task then calls this method.  This avoids having to reload the environment (as you can see by successfully referencing League in your task).

The other option is to load Rails in the script you write.  You can copy the first several lines of the binstubs (bin/rails and bin/rake) to your own file, if it's not possible to move your code into a Rails method.

Also, have you looked at the `db:fixtures:load` Rails builtin to see if that will meet your needs?

Comment: This makes perfect sense! I don't know why this wasn't blinding obvious to me. Thank you so much. Yes, the `get_fixtures.rb` doesn't need the Rails environment, as you can see in the code written. However, the `save_fixtures_to_db.rb` does.

As for the builtin `db:fixtures:load`, these are football league fixtures, as opposed to sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, for example, `bundle exec ruby "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/get_fixtures.rb"` try `bundle exec rails runner "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/get_fixtures.rb"`.

Comment: I receive the following error: `rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method 'runner' for main:Object`